# division by integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let d,k be integers, with k even.

suppose d|2k

suppose d does not divide 2

suppose d does not divide k

show that d equals 2k.

(I'm really just trying to understand the 2nd last line, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165364/242) to the question: [Prove that if $p$ is an odd prime that divides a number of the form $n^4 + 1$ then $p \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33392/prove-that-if-p-is-an-odd-prime-that-divides-a-number-of-the-form-n4-1-th))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true. Take $k=6$ and $d = 4$ for example.

Comment: You're right. I see now. 

Could you possibly explain to me how the author of the reference concludes that d = 2k in the link I provided? I'd greatly appreciate that.

Comment: @confused I don't know what the purpose of that answer was. It looks like he wanted to generalize the question to other powers of $k$, but this generalization isn't correct (with $k = 6$, $5$ is an odd divisor of $2^6 + 1$ and is not $\equiv 1 \bmod 2*6$.)